# Force Electron to display accelerator without modifier keys?

Tags: javascript, electron, hotkeys

Electron accelerators [require modifier keys](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/accelerator) - but it would be really helpful to be able to show the hotkey to the user still, even if we have to implement the logic for those handlers ourselves.

**For example, <kbd>F11</kbd> to maximize:**

[image]

Has anyone found a way to achieve this?